# How to use the LAG function to subtract the last previous record from current and place this value in a new column for Database Growth

Tags: sql, database, lag, calculation

I am trying to calculate Database growth, and using the lag function to do this:

In my example..
I would like the previous days value to be subtracted from the current days value and shown in the Difference_Previous_Day column, this is to display daily growth,

So for example I would like my most recent record on 21-11-2021 current day UsedSpaceMB(2161706mb) to  be subtracted by the USEDSpaceMB Previous day (2158844mb) to give me 2,862mb in the 'Difference_previous_Day column for current date 21-11-2021 and so on, but I appear to be getting something other value instead, see atachment, any one see what I have done wrong here?

Thanks

```
USE DATABASEGrowth
--Working on grouping by month and calculating the difference
SELECT DBName AS DatabaseName,
       Date AS CollectedDate,
       MONTH(Date) AS Month,
       DAY(Date) AS Day,
       [UsedSpace(Mb)] AS UsedSpaceMB,
       --CAST(SUM(CAST([Usedspace(Mb)] AS FLOAT)) / 1024 / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10, 3)) AS [Database Used Space GB],
       --LAG([Usedspace(Mb)]) AS previous_day,
       [Usedspace(Mb)] - LAG([Usedspace(Mb)],1,0)
            --OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS difference_previous_day 
        OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS difference_previous_day 

        
FROM DATABASEGrowth
GROUP BY DBName,
         MONTH(Date),
         Date,
         [Usedspace(Mb)],
         DAY(Date)
ORDER BY DatabaseName,
         Date DESC,
         DAY(Date),
         MONTH(Date)
```

[image]

Tried to amend SQL to carry out calculation required for me to view my daily growth.

Comment: Shouldn't you have DBName in `OVER (ORDER BY ...), as well? Or at least PARTITION BY it. If you have multiple databases...

Comment: sorry, I meant to say '...LAG(..) OVER (PARTITION BY DbName ORDER BY Date)...`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have other databases (DbName). The way you called the LAG function did not specify an order for them; therefore rows from another database might be retrieved. You can use the PARTITION BY clause to be make it specific to each database:

```
...
[Usedspace(Mb)] 
  - LAG([Usedspace(Mb)],1,0)
       OVER (PARTITION BY DbName ORDER BY Date) AS difference_previous_day 
...
```